# Move to next item in a custom IEnumerable, inside the object

Tags: c#, linq, inheritance

I have a custom object which inherits from `IEnumerable`. I need a method inside this class which will navigate to the next item in the list, and loop back to the beginning accordingly.

Some sample code is below:

```
public class Enrolments : IEnumerable<IEnrolment>
{
    public IEnrolment GetNextEnrolment()
    {

    }
}
```

I need the following tests to be valid

```
        IEnrolment enrolment1 = new Enrolment();
        IEnrolment enrolment2 = new Enrolment();

        Enrolments enrolments = new Enrolments {enrolment1, enrolment2};

        IEnrolment current;
        Assert.That(current, Is.EqualTo(enrolment1));

        current = enrolments.GetNextEnrolment();
        Assert.That(current, Is.EqualTo(enrolment2));

        current = enrolments.GetNextEnrolment();
        Assert.That(current, Is.EqualTo(enrolment1));

        current = enrolments.GetNextEnrolment();
        Assert.That(current, Is.EqualTo(enrolment2));
```

Comment: Well I would have thought it was a bit obvious. I don't know how to do this and have searched for suggestions. I cannot find any so thought I would ask this community. Though I did not expect such an aggressive reply.

Comment: Sorry. I did not mean to sound aggressive. What I am trying to say is that this question sounds a lot like "Can you guys do this for me?". From the question you do not show that you have made any effort at all. To be really critical; your question contains no question marks at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a list or other indexed collection as a private field then to implement this method all you need is to store an integer representing the current (or next) index.  With that, the implementation of the method is as simple as incrementing the indexed, modding it by the collection length (to get the desired wrapping behavior) and then returning the item at that index:

```
public class Enrolments : IEnumerable<IEnrolment>
{
    private List<IEnrolment> list = new List<IEnrolment>();
    private int currentIndex;

    public IEnrolment GetNextEnrolment()
    {
        currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % list.Count;
        return list[currentIndex];
    }

    //TODO implementations of Add and GetEnumerator
}
```

Note that rather than having your own `GetNextEnrolment` method it would be more conventional to instead have an `IEnumerable<IEnrolment>` that simply went on forever, repeatedly iterating itself, rather than this one custom method.  Rather than special casing it for this one, you can use a general method to repeat any sequence forever:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Repeat<T>(IEnumerable<T> sequence)
{
    while (true)
    {
        foreach (var item in sequence)
            yield return item;
    }
}
```

Using that, since your sequence implements `IEnumerable<IEnrolment>` already you could do:

```
Enrollments enrollments = new Enrollments(enrollment1, enrollment2);

IEnumerable<IEnrolment> repeatingSequence = Repeat(enrollments);
```

The advantage here is that you could `foreach` over that repeating sequence (although you'll want a `break` under some condition if you do that, unless you plan to go forever), use LINQ operations on it, or rely on other generic helper methods based around `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: Thanks for the great reply :). I'll take a look at this at work today

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use the [IEnumerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t2267t6.aspx) interface. This will work:

```
IEnrollment enrollment1 = new Enrollment();
IEnrollment enrollment2 = new Enrollment();

Enrollments enrollments = new Enrollments(enrollment1, enrollment2);
IEnumerator<IEnrollment> enumerator = enrollment.GetEnumerator();

enumerator.MoveNext();
Assert.That(enumerator.Current, Is.EqualTo(enrollment1));

enumerator.MoveNext();
Assert.That(enumerator.Current, Is.EqualTo(enrollment2));

enumerator.Reset(); // Move back to the beginning of the list

enumerator.MoveNext();
Assert.That(enumerator.Current, Is.EqualTo(enrollment1));

enumerator.MoveNext();
Assert.That(enumerator.Current, Is.EqualTo(enrollment2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of yield for this

Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) link for a description